# How to define direction in request with pageable parameter?

Tags: java, api, kotlin, request, pageable

I have a query that takes pageable as a parameter. I define the direction as DESC but this takes no effect. This is my request. Could you please help me formulate the requests in a way that the results come back sorted in descending order?
I have posted my request in the  picture below. It works but it does not sort the results

Thank you
[image]

This is the controller code:

```
@GetMapping
fun listMessages(@RequestParam conversationRef: String,
                 @RequestParam fromDate: Instant, @RequestParam toDate: Instant, 
                 pageable: Pageable): PaginatedCollection<MessageVO> {
                     return messageService.listAll(fromDate, toDate, pageable, 
                              conversationRef).data ?: PaginatedCollection(listOf(), 
                              PaginationVO.build(), SortVO.build())
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: You are right. Updated

Comment: the sort field in the Pageable is a class that contains at least two values. The direction of the sort and the field on which to sort. Read https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#paging-and-sorting.sorting

Comment: Yes. I know. The format of the request is what I havent figured out

Comment: Like how do I add the field to sort, in the context of a postman request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send sort field for which you want to sort by descending.([Ref](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#paging-and-sorting.sorting))  Ex:

`http://localhost:8080/people?sort=id,desc`

Here `id` is sort field and `desc` is sort direction separated by a comma.

So, you need to send `id,desc` on `sort` param in PostMan for sort by `id` in desecending order.

Comment: if you want multiple soring then you can add like: http://localhost:8080/people?sort=id,desc&sort=name,desc&time,asc NOTE that default is asc